# Is it possible to create a catch-all open cover using a countable collection of open balls?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $(X,d)$ be an arbitrary metric space and $A \subset X$ be a nonempty set. Letting $\epsilon > 0$, is it possible to create an open cover, $U$, of $A$, such that $$U = \lbrace B_{\epsilon}(x_{\alpha}) \rbrace_{\alpha \in \mathbb{N}}$$ for $x_{\alpha} \in A$?

Clearly, I could've indexed every point in $A$ and that would work as an open cover, but I'm interested in having the open cover consist of the $\epsilon$-balls of a countable number of elements in $A$. My intuition (or rather lack thereof) tells me that this shouldn't work for any metric space, although I feel as if there might be a way to make this idea work in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and similar (pretty vague notion, I know) metric spaces. For what metric spaces might this work?

Comment: It works in *separable* metric spaces, such as $\mathbb R^n.$ (That means metric spaces having a countable dense subset.) It doesn't work, for example, if $X$ is an uncountable set and $d(x,y)=1$ whenever $x\ne y.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it for any $\epsilon\le 1$ if $d$ is the discrete metric on an uncountable set. More generally, you can't do it for arbitrary sets and $\epsilon$ in non-separable metric spaces.

Comment: I guess separability is why I thought it could work for $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and some other metric spaces, but I just didn't have the term pinned. Makes a lot of sense, thanks!

Comment: @CauchyPotato: You're welcome!

Comment: @Brian [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2030536/242) could use more undeletion votes to reverse the mindless Community bot.

Comment: Bill: Done. Duplicates with good answers should always be kept.

Answer (score 0):

Define the following metric on $\mathbb R^+$:

$d(x,y)=\max(x,y)$ if $x\neq y$ and $0$ otherwise.

Clearly it cannot be covered with a numerable number of balls of radius $\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon$ (since the only ball of radius $\epsilon$ containing a number $x>\epsilon$ is the singleton $\{x\}$)